# Z test vs Wald Test in logistic regression

Tags: logistic

I am looking at logistic regression output that shows Z test values. When can I use these to estimate the significance of coefficients, and when do I need to use a Wald chi-squared test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are almost certainly the same thing. The "Z test values" in your logistic regression output are probably Wald statistics, and the Wald chi-square statistic is probably just $Z^2$. This means that the Wald chi-squared test is the same as a two-sided test using the corresponding $Z$-value.

Comment: So just to be clear - if I need the Wald's Chi-Square value, all I need to do is take a square of the Z statistic from the output?